# Issue with table of content in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I have an issue with the table of content. As you see in the picture, the number of dots in 'Chapter Five' is not enough. Would any one please help me with that? Thank you so very much.

[image]

Comment: Impossible to answer without examining a copy of the document.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer without having a look at the document. However, the most possible reason would be that the TOC (Table Of Contents) level of *Chapter Five* is not correct, or else the TOC levels are modified. If the level is incorrect you can always change it in the document, or if the TOC levels are modified a simple reset would resolve your problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have "Chapter Five" formated as TOC style. Change it to whatever the chapter style should be.

Open the Styles sidebar (Alt-Ctrl-Shift+S).
Select the "Chapter Five" text and see what style in the sidebar is highlighted.
Pick the style that it should be.
If you don't know what it should be, click on a different chapter heading to see which style it is (probably something like Heading 1).

Answer (score 0):

As was commented, impossible to tell without the actual document.
My guess would be the tab settings in the TOC *style* for that level need to be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

If the format of other chapters in the table of content is correct, such as "Chapter Four" or "Chapter Three".
You only need to use the **Format Painter** to paste the correct chapter format into "Chapter Five".